# Program hangs after calling Dispose()

Tags: c#, multithreading, sockets, webcam, dispose

I'm working on an iOS project with C#. The program captures images from a connected webcam and sends it via Socket to the iPhone/iPad. This all works fine and I can successfully get my stream showing up on the device.

But when the client disconnects, the webcam has to get turned off and in this function, the program just hangs up. No error messages and no exception calls...just hangs! I believe it's a problem with multiple threads but unfortunately I'm not as experienced in C# to find a solution. I hope someone here can bring me on the right track...

Code:
onImageCaptured function:

```
public void OnImageCaptured(Touchless.Vision.Contracts.IFrameSource frameSource, Touchless.Vision.Contracts.Frame frame, double fps)
{
    _latestFrame = frame.Image;
    Console.WriteLine("OnImageCaptured");
    if (isConnected)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("OnImageCaptured - isConnected");
        byteArray = new byte[0];
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();

        _latestFrame.Save(stream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        stream.Close();
        byteArray = stream.ToArray();

        if (byteArray.Length > 0)
        {
            string eof = "<EOF>";
            byte[] eofByte = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(eof);
            Console.WriteLine("OnImageCaptured - sendStream");
            this.onDataSend(byteArray);
            this.onDataSend(eofByte);
            stream.Flush();
        }

        System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Log(0, "1", "\nByte Array Length: " + byteArray.Length.ToString());
    }
    pictureBoxDisplay.Invalidate();
}
```

Defined like this in Camera Class:

```
public event EventHandler<CameraEventArgs> OnImageCaptured;
```

And triggered:

```
OnImageCaptured.Invoke(this, new CameraEventArgs(bitmap, fps));
```

So this function - what i believe - runs in a separate threat since the UI is not blocked when the images are coming in.

So next the client disconnection is handled in this function:

```
public void onDataSend(byte[] data)
{
    clientReady = false;
    try
    {
        socketWorker.Send(data);
    }
    catch (SocketException se)
    {
        isConnected = false;
        Console.WriteLine("Error: Data Write - SocketException");
        Console.WriteLine(se.ErrorCode.ToString());
        thrashOldCamera() // THIS FUNCTION HANGS THE PROGRAM !!
        onDisconnectServer();

        // onDisconnectServer();
    }
    catch (ObjectDisposedException)
    {
        isConnected = false;
        Console.WriteLine("Error: Data Write - ObjectDisposedException");
        // onDisconnectServer();
    }

}
```

Client disconnects, `thrashOldCamera()` is called. Works fine so far! Now:

```
private void thrashOldCamera()
{
    Console.WriteLine("TrashOldCamera");
    // Trash the old camera
    if (_frameSource != null)
    {
        try
        {
            _frameSource.NewFrame -= OnImageCaptured;
            Console.WriteLine("TrashOldCamera - 1");
            _frameSource.Camera.Dispose(); // HERE IT HANGS. IT NEVER GOES PAST HERE !!!
            Console.WriteLine("TrashOldCamera - 2");
            setFrameSource(null);
            Console.WriteLine("TrashOldCamera - 3");
            pictureBoxDisplay.Paint -= new PaintEventHandler(drawLatestImage);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("End Trash Camera Ex: " + ex);
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine("End Trash Camera");
}
```

The program hangs at `_frameSource.Camera.Dispose();`. As stated above, there's no error or exception. 
It may be a problem that `onDataReceive()` gets called within the `onImageCapture` function(). 
I also added a button to the form that triggers `thrashOldCamera()` and this works perfectly.

Any help/hints are truly appreciated.

Comment: http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/-NET-Debugging-Stater-Kit-for-the-Production-Environment/Diagnosing-Application-Issues-01

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is called deadlock, a typical threading problem.  I don't see you explicitly invoke to the UI thread anywhere in the snippet so the deadlock is possibly located in the camera firmware itself.  The core issue is that you are trying to close the camera *while* its callback is still executing, there's not a lot of code that's resilient to that.  The Release() call can't complete until the callback completes.  But the callback can't complete until the Release() call completes.  Deadlock city.

You'll need to restructure your code so this cannot happen.  Delaying releasing the camera is key, best done on the same thread that opened the camera.  You'll probably solve it by releasing it in the FormClosed event for example.  Or not releasing it at all and leaving it up to Windows to automatically close handles.

Answer (score 3):

Don't know if this really should be a comment or a answer, but at least I can get you down the right track.

I [found the source](http://touchless.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/55790) to the library you are using. This is the contents of `Camera.Dispose()`

```
public void Dispose()
{
    StopCapture();
}
```

Ok, not much help there, here is `Camera.StopCapture()`

```
internal void StopCapture()
{
    _cameraMethods.StopCamera();
}
```

One again, not much help. `_cameraMethods` is a type of `CameraMethods` which comes from the library `WebCamLib` which is a C++ helper library to communicate with direct show.

Here is `CameraMethods::StopCamera()`

```
void CameraMethods::StopCamera()
{
    if (g_pMediaControl != NULL)
    {
        g_pMediaControl->Stop();
        g_pMediaControl->Release();
        g_pMediaControl = NULL;
    }

    g_pfnCaptureCallback = NULL;

    if (g_pIBaseFilterNullRenderer != NULL)
    {
        g_pIBaseFilterNullRenderer->Release();
        g_pIBaseFilterNullRenderer = NULL;
    }

    if (g_pIBaseFilterSampleGrabber != NULL)
    {
        g_pIBaseFilterSampleGrabber->Release();
        g_pIBaseFilterSampleGrabber = NULL;
    }

    if (g_pIBaseFilterCam != NULL)
    {
        g_pIBaseFilterCam->Release();
        g_pIBaseFilterCam = NULL;
    }

    if (g_pGraphBuilder != NULL)
    {
        g_pGraphBuilder->Release();
        g_pGraphBuilder = NULL;
    }

    if (g_pCaptureGraphBuilder != NULL)
    {
        g_pCaptureGraphBuilder->Release();
        g_pCaptureGraphBuilder = NULL;
    }

    this->activeCameraIndex = -1;
}
```

It appears your exception is being eaten during the native to managed boundary. I don't know how much this will help you but at least it gives you a start of where to look.

Enable unmanaged code debugging and see if you can step through the Libraries source and see where the real problem is.

[image]

I am making this a community wiki if anyone else who has more experience with C++/C# interop wants to edit this and add more of what to do next to debug the issue.

Comment: Hello Scott. Thx for your answer. It sure breaks somewhere in there but this is way over my visual c# - c++ level to find a solution. I guess I have to look for another webcam script that does not use directShow.

Answer (score 0):

Find the event to invoke while the device is disconnected. Write the code to turn off the web cam there.

Comment: Hi Gijo, not exactly sure what you mean by that?

Comment: There might be an event that you can use to write code for turning off the web cam. May be you can check the eventlist available with the control.

Comment: so what i just noticed, there is a function called 'void Dispose()' in the Camera class. If I use the button to turn of the camera - which works fine - this method is not triggered. If a client disconnects, it however triggers this dispose function

Comment: ok, you can write the code on void Dispose function to turn off the camera.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case there is still an issue with it, Use the **Touchless.RefreshCameraList** to disconnect from the camera you can also add the **Touchless.CurrentCamera.Dispose** if ya so wish to. You may still need to enable unmannaged code debugging